# codeigniter display error: Unable to locate the model you have specified:

Tags: codeigniter

I use latest version of CI, that is 2.1.2.

I upload my demo application in the following location http://www.domainname.com/myfolder/index.php

If i try to open home page, welcome controller is opened correctly. However if I try to open http://www.domainname.com/myfolder/index.php/controllername/functionname page, I get the following error message:

An Error Was Encountered

Unable to locate the model you have specified: backofficeusersmodel

In my config file, I have the following settings:

$config[‘base_url’] = ‘http://www.domainname/myfolder/’;
$config[‘index_page’] = ‘index.php’;
I also tried and

$config[‘base_url’] = ‘http://www.domainname.com/myfolder/application/’;
$config[‘index_page’] = ‘index.php’;

without any success.

However, the model is uploaded and its name is backOfficeUsersModel, not as stated in the error message all lover case.

I would like to mention that I use myModel (uploaded in application/core), and that same strange thing was happening when I upload same application under some free hosting, just there the error was that mymodel could not be located.

I upload same application on different hosting company and there it worked. Also, same application work normally on my localhost.

Anyone had similar experience?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Model files should be in application/models folder and should be named in lower case like backofficeusersmodel. Probably there is a deficiency in these requirements.

Comment: Indeed. As soon as I rename the model in all lovercase, application started to work. Thanks for the help